# Intonation changes meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, spoken-english, american-accent, intonation

The [audio](https://mp3.fastupload.co/files/1624699312) includes two short conversations in which the speaker answers with different intonations of "pretty" so as to cause different meanings of the two answers. The second one means she didn't like the movie much. Why? Is that a sarcastic tone?

Comment: IMO the second one is not sarcasm, but giving *reserved* or *weak* praise to the movie. She did not dislike it; it could have been better.

Comment: @Weather Vane So, when Americans or native English speakers wanna express something they don't like it much, do they always use "pretty" with that kind of pitch?

Comment: Not always, intonation can be used in many ways.

Comment: Not just different intonations of 'pretty', but also of 'good'! The first reply emphasises 'good', the second emphasises 'pretty', implying that the film was only _fairly_ good.

Comment: What if one wanna express "really good" with "pretty", what intonation pattern will it be?

Comment: As in the first of the two sound bites, but with 'really'.

Comment: @questionguy - you should use 'want to' rather than 'wanna', which is severely casual, dialectical and informal.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh. It is "good" to be stressed instead of "pretty" if one would like to express more than good.

Comment: You can stress both of them: "it was **really good**!"

Comment: So, it is same to both stress "pretty good", right? But, if one only stresses "really" or " pretty", that means one doesn't like it much, does it?

Comment: You would not say 'really' if you meant 'not much', unless sarcasm was intended. There aren't any rules about what someone will say. They say something, and you infer from their tone what they mean, which isn't always what they intended (say with sarcsasm). The sound bites are *examples* of the ways to use intonation. Isn't that the way in any language?